# turn off features during training in deep network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

I'm looking for a solution at the following problem:
I have my neural network with 8 features and 6 outputs.

The network predicts some info on a graph, where a record is related to a node in the graph.
It works perfectly when I have all the examples (nodes) with the same degree of neighbours.
Now I would need it to work also for nodes with less neighbours, but on a general form, meaning that I do not know a priori how many they are.

Thus I tried putting a zero when the the neighbour does not exist, but the predictions where all strange, not correct at all.

So my questions is: is there a way such that during training I can switch off some input neurons looking at how many effective features I have on that example?

To be more precise: the first example taken by the NN has the full neighbour, thus I have 8 values; the second has 6 values, so I would like to switch off 2 input neurons and so on.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which might work would be to declare a feature as non relevant. So you simply specify a value, which makes the model learn that it should not be used in this iteration. So when you set the values to zero, the model wll just think that its a zero, so the meaning is ambiguus. However if you set it to -1 e.G. but -1 does not occur in your data at all, the model might be able to learn that -1 represents a non existent feature and puts more attention on the others.

Comment: So you say to create a dataset where the 'non-existing feauture' assumes -1, and only then train again the network, correct ?

Comment: Yes that would be the idea, if your data allows that

Comment: Sure theu allow it, I only need to try it! thanks man.
Just, did you thought this by your own or there is some reference talking about how to espress not existent features with non-null values ?

Comment: For sure there are references about how to deal with data like that and I might have read about it. It just came into my mind, to treat non existent values as an extra kind of value. Like when you do a classification, you can use one class for all other stuff that does not match to your classes, like an extra "stuff" class. I thought that might work at your case also. I am really interested, if it helped you

Comment: I'll try today and let you know what happens. just quickly: following your ideas, I assigne a -1 value to missing features; but before training I usually have a normalization. thus, i would obtain different negative values instead of -1. Do you think thisc could destroy the training and thus it is better to replace them with -1, or it should understand for any negative value that there is a missing feature ?

Comment: I dont think that should be a problem. As all values are set to -1, the normalization will take care, that all -1 are put into the same negative number. I think it is just important, that it is the same number

Comment: Actually I could have different feauters that in some record have -1. so the std and mean of each feature is different, thus the -1 normalized for an the input 1 is different from the -1 normalized for input 2. however I can just easily reput them to -1. the real problem is that I have a custom loss function which does som stuff, and now I would like to say "if there is -1, then just forget about it and pass on" but in keras I cannot actually put an if else statement. So ithink it should be a while before I can tell you some results